# Duplicating Eclipse run configurations created by the Angular2 CLI plugin

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, angular, angular-cli, run-configuration

I'm running Eclipse Neon (4.6) with the [Angular 2 plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse). This plugin creates a couple of run configurations that are accessible under the Run As right-click menu, namely `ng build` and `ng serve`. Basically, these two configurations invoke the Angular CLI (`ng`) and issue the `build` or `serve` commands. It is my understanding that these configurations are defined directly by the plugin.

Currently, I can invoke unit tests for Angular 2 projects by opening a terminal view and typing `ng test`. It would be easier to just have that as a Run As configuration. So I thought I would create a new configuration. I see that there is an AgularCLI entry in the Run Configurations management window, but unfortunately, trying to create a run configuration therein results in a dialog box saying that there is "no tab group defined for launch configuration type ts.eclipse.ide.angular2.cli.angularCLILaunchConfigurationType".

Is there any way I can go about twisting Eclipse's arm so that I can launch unit tests from a right-click menu rather than having to go through the trouble of launching a terminal?

Comment: Please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues

Comment: Done, thanks for piping in. Created two, actually. The more general question still stands, though. Is there a way to duplicate plugin-generated configurations?

Comment: See https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues/23

Comment: The error is described in https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues/24 (not 23). As @angelo says "I have not implemented UI for Angular CLI launch"

Comment: I'm implementing this feature. It starts working. It misses just an "arguments" text box in the launch. It will be available for 1.1.0 which will be soon released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that you install [Angular2 Eclipse 1.1.0](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.1.0) which fixes several bugs:

1. fix bug with duplicated launch
2. add ng test
3. provide an UI for ng launch

[image: ng launch UI]

4. you can execute now ng commands with angular-cli.json editor:

[image: ng editor]